# Any way to increase the amount of water that flows through bedrock?

Tags: hydrology

My pond is fed by a spring that collects inside a large concrete box (6' x 6' x 8'deep) that was formed up many years ago.  The walls of this box are sitting on bedrock.  Small trickles of water seep through the bedrock when I clean the sand buildup out every ten years or so.  My question is, would drilling holes into the bedrock likely help or hurt the amount of water that is coming into the box?

Comment: It would seem that the bedrock surface has a spring of some sort. You might be able to drill a well hole to the water source underneath the rock overhang and turn the trickle from the cracks into an artesian wells. I'd expect that someone who drills well in your area could give a rational discussion of the options

Comment: Not enough information I'm afraid. You would need to know where the water comes from and through. Drilling a few 5 meter holes makes no difference if the water has to seep through another 500 meters.

Comment: Spray your concrete box with "Rhino Liner" inside or outside and it will be water proof and easier to clean out the sand every ten years.